# Liftering cutoff

Tags: signal-processing, fft, spectrum

Is there a rule of thumb in deciding the cut-off value when performing the low time liftering process in Cepstral analysis? Or is it just trial and error analysis?

I am trying to calculate the spectral envelope of the frequency response of data obtained from a vibration sensor. Sampling frequency is 5000 Hz.

Comment: For those who might downvote this question on the basis of apparent dyslexia of the OP, think again.

Comment: Mr.Sifferman, would you like to elaborate on that 'dyslexia' comment ? Why would this question make anyone think I have dyslexia ? I don't get it.

Comment: Because "liftering" looks like "filtering" misspelled. You asked a legitimate question, a good question, but somebody downvoted it, I can only imagine on the assumption of lousy spelling. I was about to edit your post for spelling until I googled "Cepstral Analysis" and learned about low-time liftering.

Comment: I understand. I guess not many know about cepstral analysis. I couldn't add it as a tag to the question since it wasn't available in the suggestions.

Comment: This is really, really cool to find out, but I think this also belongs on EE or DSP stack exchange, or maybe Math.SE.

Comment: Thank you. I have  added the question on DSP SE too. Haven't found an answer yet. I now understand that this question is inappropriate here. So I will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done a project on *cepstral analysis* and found that **15 or 20** is the *low-time liftering cut-off*.

To my application 15 seemed to be pretty good.

Both the values are acceptable and works good.

But think for your application.

And I don't think there exist any rule or formula to calculate it.
Because it works well for all kinds of values and signals.

So it must be trail and error by someone who ended up in this value.